# Cefsharp InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I updated the chromium from 75.x.x to 85.x.x (latest) and to my surprise it is giving error to `InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired()`

My code:

```
private void Chrm_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => tabControl.SelectedTab.Text = e.title);
}
private void Chrm_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() =>
    {
           url.Text = e.Address;
    });
}
```

Error message: 'MyForm' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired' and no accessible extension method 'InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired' accepting a first argument of type 'MyForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any advice how to change that code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only takes 5 minutes to search the CefSharp issues on GitHub to find out the reason: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2983

You can get around this by adding the following class to your project, which is copied from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/75/CefSharp.WinForms/Internals/ControlExtensions.cs#L20:

```cs
public static class MyControlExtensions
{
    public static void InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
        else
        {
            action.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

However, a bigger issue is that you are calling this method in the wrong way. You should be using the control **being modified**:

```cs
tabControl.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => tabControl.SelectedTab.Text = e.title);

url.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => url.Text = e.Address);
```

Comment: Last part is not correct, using the form object is the more sensible way.

Comment: I added the ControlExtensions.cs to my project and now works fine thanks. Sorry i really not found that on google that they removed this component from CefSharp.